# Jquery click function only seems to be working once

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, click

I'm trying to pre-select a radio button based on a button click further up the page. The below code does work but it only seems to correctly select the radio option once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".select-one").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_0']").attr("checked", true);
});
   jQuery(".select-two").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_1']").attr("checked", true);
});
   jQuery(".select-three").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_2']").attr("checked", true);
});
});
```

Is there anything I can add to this code to enable it to run each time the button is clicked? Any help much appreciated.

[JFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5oega1mh/)

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Thanks for the [mcve] - if you look at the source of your page after clicking all the "buttons" (links), all of them have an *attribute* of `checked="checked"`.  You need to use `.prop("checked", true);` to set the checked property, then it will work fine.

Comment: I have edited my original post with a example of what is happening

Comment: You need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you both for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: prop vs attr... clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978870/jquery-prop-vs-attr-clarification)

Comment: Or this: [prop() vs attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: TBH it's still a bit confusing - some people suggest *always* using `.prop` (and have downvoted answers that correctly suggest using `.attr`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".select-one").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_0']").prop("checked", true);
});
   jQuery(".select-two").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_1']").prop("checked", true);
});
   jQuery(".select-three").on('click', function(){
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][id='choice_25_25_2']").prop("checked", true);
});
});
```